# cannot toggle NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I read that if you write out `nnoremap <C-e> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>`, you can toggle NERDTree viewer - if you don't start NERDTree yet and type in `Control+E`, then you can open the NERDTree viewer, and if you already opened it, you can close the NERDTree in the same way as you type in `:NERDTreeToggle`.

However, when I try to do the same, I can successfully open it - but I cannot close it and the screen remains the same except the main title slightly changes, such as from `NERD_tree_1` to `NERD_tree_2`.

So how can I use the toggle functionality? Or do I get it wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have noticed you are using `inoremap` which binds a C-e in Insert Mode only.

I have tried your way on my VIM installation, and indeed it will type `:NERDTreeToggle` in insert mode on pressing C-e.
While in normal mode there is no effect.

If it is a mistake, try changing to:

```
nnoremap <C-e> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

I added it in `.vimrc` - it works fine.
Also, if you still run into a problem, give another hotkey a try, you might be clashing with other binds.

Comment: Oops. I actually wrote out `nmoremap`, not `inoremap` in my `.vimrc`, but failed to type it correctly in the original question. Now fixed.

Comment: @user2360798 alright. the NERDTreeToggle is the right way to bind. I suggest you trying another hotkey, for instance F5 to verify it is not an issue due to hotkey, but something else. Here is an example of my bind: nnoremap <silent> <F6> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

Comment: When I tried to set `Control+N` to the toggle functionality, it worked as expected. However, even after I reset the mapping and restart, it still work like typing `Control+N` leads to the toggle and not go back to the previous settings...

Comment: Weird. If typing manually :NERDTreeToggle and hitting Enter works, then you shall reformulate the question into why your bind does not work. In addition providing some information for us to work from. "It does not work" is not enough :(. If :NERDTreeToggle does not as expected, then you could actually debug it by observing the sourcecode in .vim/plugin

Comment: After I read your answer and comment, I suspected some of my vim settings conflicted with something... So I just removed `NERDTree` and re-installed it, then the toggle worked by typing `Control+E`. However, typing `Control+N` still leads to the toggle and not to the one that I previously mapped... Maybe just because deleting the map setting doesn't lead to reverting to the previous mapping? Thanks a lot for the original question though.

Comment: You are welcome :) All the mapping are assigned through config files (.vimrc, and .vim folder) once you restart VIM, there is no secret 'memory' where VIM would store temporary mapping after restarting program. Considering you are on linux, you could look up for <C-n> maps using find and grep. If you are in .vim folder: find . | xargs grep -n "<C-n>". Also do not forget about checking the .vimrc for <C-n> itself.